# Switch to GUI in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: gui, 17.04

I made some changes on my system to allow me to instantly boot into the terminal, not a GUI.

Now I want to go back to GUI, but I'm not sure how.

Here's [the instructions I followed](http://linux.m2osw.com/boot-command-line-console-ubuntu-1604) to boot straight into the terminal. (The instructions are for 16.04 because that's when I made the computer boot straight into a terminal but I've updated to 17.04 since then).

Comment: First what problem was that you had, second a restart should start the GUI, unless you fiddled with it... And your title says `17.04` but post `16.04` !

Comment: I did fiddle with it.  I followed the instructions here I order to boot straight into console:    http://linux.m2osw.com/boot-command-line-console-ubuntu-1604

Comment: Where are the instructions you followed?

Comment: I edited the comment to include a link.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Answer (score 4):

To get back to the `GUI` mode in the console mode run this command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Then restart the system, after which you should edit the `/etc/default/grub` and remove the `text` added previously.

Optionally, to suppress the kernel output during boot, change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
```

to this or **how it was in your setup previously**:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` from your terminal to have to update Grub.

Comment: Now what. The command runs without any errors but I'm still in console.

Comment: So I did that but now it loads forever, it gets to "Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done." but it stays there. Doesn't do anything at all. But I'm able to press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and I can open a terminal and it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Again that's the standard way to return from non-GUI setup after changing the default run target like you did. Most likely you did more than you said and or you didn't follow my answer religiously. If you plan on using your computer as a desktop then I suggest you take time and try again.

Comment: I was able to fix problem by doing a factory reset. Yeah

Answer (score 0):

you can move to console anytime by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and return to GUI at anytime using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.